# Adding new dataframe colonms using information extracted from the url in the url column, but the url could be missing information

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Given:** A pandas dataframe that contains a `user_url` column among other columns.

**Expectation:** New columns added to the original dataframe where the columns are composed of information extracted from the URL in the `user_url` column. Those columns being `car_make`, `model`, `year` and `user_id`.

**Some Extra info:** We know that the `car_make` will only contain letters either with or without a '-'. The `model` can contain any characters. The `year` will only be 4 digits long. The `user_id` will consist of digits of any length.

I tired using a regex to split the url but it failed when there was missing information or extra information. I also tried just splinting the data but I has the same issue using split.

**Given dataframe**

```
    mpg  miles                                           user_url  
0   NaN    NaN    https://www.somewebsite.com/suzuki/swift/2015/674857 
1  31.6    NaN      https://www.somewebsite.com/bmw/x3/2009/461150  
2  28.5    NaN  https://www.somewebsite.com/mercedes-benz/e300/1998/13  
3  46.8    NaN            https://www.somewebsite.com/320d/2010/247233  
4  21.0  244.4     https://www.somewebsite.com/honda/pass/2019/1038865
5  25.0  254.4        https://www.somewebsite.com/volkswagen/passat/11
```

**Expected Dataframe**

```
    mpg  miles                                           user_url        car_make     model   year \
0   NaN    NaN   https://www.somewebsite.com/suzuki/swift/2015/674857   suzuki         swift  2015
1  31.6    NaN         https://www.somewebsite.com/bmw/x3/2009/461150   bmw               x3  2009
2  28.5    NaN  https://www.somewebsite.com/mercedes-benz/e300/1998/13  mercedes-benz   e300  1998
3  46.8    NaN           https://www.somewebsite.com/320d/2010/247233   NaN             320d  2010
4  21.0  244.4    https://www.somewebsite.com/honda/pass/2019/1038865   honda           pass  2019
5  25.0  254.4       https://www.somewebsite.com/volkswagen/passat/11   volkswagen    passat   NaN

   user_id  
0   674857
1   461150
2       13
3   247233
4  1038865
5       11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to do

```
split=df['user_url'].str.split("/", n = 4, expand = True)
df['car_make']=split[3]
 df.loc[df['car_make'].str.contains('1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0'),'car_make']=np.nan
```

Comment: This didn't work because the urls aren't guaranteed to contain all the field values i want to extract. Look at entry three the `car_make` is missing in the url and your solution just puts the `model` in were the `car_make` would go.

Comment: ok then why don't you list all the car's brands and then apply a fuzzyword/fuzzymatch for example with fuzzywuzzy. Before the comparison you put everything in lower case

Comment: Cool thanks the fuzzyword/fuzzy match really helped me, it also helped me when the other fields weren't in the url and when there was extra data in the url.